# where to add permission to tomcat and mobile first server (worklight) in ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, ubuntu-14.04, worklight-server, worklight-runtime

I am configuring Mobile First Server v7.1 on Ubuntu 14.04. I have installed tomcat on the same machine. I am not understanding where to specify permission. Is it required to give execute permission to worklight server setup folder?

For Apache Tomcat, you must have the right to perform the following actions:

- Read the configuration directory.
- Create backup files and modify files in the configuration directory, such as server.xml and tomcatusers.xml
- Create backup files and modify files in the bin directory, such as setenv.bat.
- Create files in the lib directory.
- Create files in the webapps directory.

Actually, I am getting following error so I thought it may be because of permissions.

```
Buildfile: /root/.mobilefirst_platform_server/server-configuration-tool/Configuration_SALESDEMO/SALESDEMO.xml

adminstall:
[installworklightadmin] Logging output of task <installWorklightAdmin> to file /root/.mobilefirst_platform_server/configuration-logs/installWorklightAdmin_2017_06_19_08_42_30.log
[installworklightadmin] java.lang.NullPointerException
[installworklightadmin]  at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppServerTask.getBackupFileNextId(AppServerTask.java:6358)
[installworklightadmin]  at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AdminAppServerTask.makeTomcatJMXRMIEnvScript(AdminAppServerTask.java:1029)
[installworklightadmin]  at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AdminAppServerTask.buildAndProcessItems(AdminAppServerTask.java:1142)
[installworklightadmin]  at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppServerTask.setupBuildAndProcessItems(AppServerTask.java:3064)
[installworklightadmin]  at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppServerTask.doExecute(AppServerTask.java:307)
[installworklightadmin]  at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.InstallWorklightAdminTask.execute(InstallWorklightAdminTask.java:43)
[installworklightadmin]  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
[installworklightadmin]  at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
[installworklightadmin]  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
[installworklightadmin]  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
[installworklightadmin]  at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
[installworklightadmin]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
[installworklightadmin]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
[installworklightadmin]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
[installworklightadmin]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
[installworklightadmin]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
[installworklightadmin]  at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
[installworklightadmin]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
[installworklightadmin]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
[installworklightadmin]  at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
[installworklightadmin]  at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
[installworklightadmin]  at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

BUILD FAILED
/root/.mobilefirst_platform_server/server-configuration-tool/Configuration_SALESDEMO/SALESDEMO.xml:74: java.lang.NullPointerException
 at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppServerTask.getBackupFileNextId(AppServerTask.java:6358)
 at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AdminAppServerTask.makeTomcatJMXRMIEnvScript(AdminAppServerTask.java:1029)
 at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AdminAppServerTask.buildAndProcessItems(AdminAppServerTask.java:1142)
 at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppServerTask.setupBuildAndProcessItems(AppServerTask.java:3064)
 at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.AppServerTask.doExecute(AppServerTask.java:307)
 at com.ibm.worklight.config.ant.appserver.InstallWorklightAdminTask.execute(InstallWorklightAdminTask.java:43)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
 at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor6.invoke(Unknown Source)
 at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.DefaultExecutor.executeTargets(DefaultExecutor.java:41)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.runBuild(Main.java:851)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.Main.startAnt(Main.java:235)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.run(Launcher.java:280)
 at org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:109)

Total time: 1 second
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not think you will need to give any specific permission as such unless you are encountering any specific errors (which you can share).

Once you have installed the Mobile First Server, you can use the Server Configuration Tool to configure the mobile first with tomcat as web server.

The details of the steps needed to configure the same can be found here: https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSHS8R_7.1.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/deploy/c_using_server_config_tool.html

Comment: Can you explain the steps that results in the above error ?